# How to replace the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have below string --

```
ss = 'command: $username = "abcd" ; $password = "abcdefgh" ; $secStringPassword
          = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force ; $credObject = New-Object
          System.Management.Automation.sdsasassas($userName, $secStringPassword);'
```

Want a output with replacing the password as ********
output

```
'command: $username = "abcd" ; $password = ******** ; $secStringPassword
          = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force ; $credObject = New-Object
          System.Management.Automation.sdsasassas($userName, $secStringPassword);'
```

tried with `gsub` but not able to achieve. How can I made his change( with out any extra 3rd party library).

Comment: I want to mask the password as ********* otherwise it shows as a plain text in the logs. I have to change it after I got the string only

Comment: there's an [edit] button right under your question.

Comment: `ss.gsub!(/(?<=password = )("?)[^"\s;]+\1/,'"******"')` ?

Comment: Thanks Jad for the solution - 
I tried with the below solution, it's also working
puts ss.gsub(/(password = )(\W+\w+\W)/) { $1 + "*" * $2.length }

Answer (score 1):

You can use gsub and sub, referencing the matched groups:

```rb
ss.gsub!(/(\$password = )(".*")(\ ;)/) do 
  "#{$1}#{$2.sub(/.*/, "*"*($2.size))} ;"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Thiago for the solution, I tried with the below solution,it's also working 
puts ss.gsub(/(password = )(\W+\w+\W)/) { $1 + "*" * $2.length }

One query I have --- 
how this $1 and $2 works, that's not clear to me. pls give some light on this some links so I can study on that

Comment: The regex is separeted by groups. First: (\$password = ) which matches with "$password = " , then (".*") is the password with ", and the last one is (\ ;) which matches with " ;" after the password. Each group is assigned, in order, with $ variables. So, $1 is the first group, $2 is the second and so on...

Comment: I use https://rubular.com/ to test regex's and these sources have a good start point for regex: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/advanced/regular_expressions.html and https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/

Comment: But, if you want to go deeper in regex, I would recommend to study formal languages and automata theory. (Also, my english is not very trained, so feel free to correct me or ask if something is unclear)